# Existential type in higher order function

Tags: haskell, existential-type

I've got a function whose job is to compute some optimal value of type `a` wrt some value function of type `a -> v`

```
type OptiF a v = (a -> v) -> a
```

Then I have a container that wants to store such a function together with another function which uses the values values:

```
data Container a = forall v. (Ord v) => Cons (OptiF a v) (a -> Int)
```

The idea is that whoever implements a function of type `OptiF a v` should not be bothered with the details of `v` except that it's an instance of `Ord`.

So I've written a function which takes such a value function and a container. Using the `OptiF a v` it should compute the optimal value wrt `val` and plug it in the container's `result` function:

```
optimize :: (forall v. (Ord v) => a -> v) -> Container a -> Int
optimize val (Cons opti result) = result (opti val)
```

So far so good, but I can't call `optimize`, because

```
callOptimize :: Int
callOptimize = optimize val cont
   where val = (*3)
         opti val' = if val' 1 > val' 0 then 100 else -100
         cont = Cons opti (*2)
```

does not compile:

```
Could not deduce (v ~ Int)
from the context (Ord v)
  bound by a type expected by the context: Ord v => Int -> v
  at bla.hs:12:16-32
  `v' is a rigid type variable bound by
      a type expected by the context: Ord v => Int -> v at bla.hs:12:16
Expected type: Int
  Actual type: Int
Expected type: Int -> v
  Actual type: Int -> Int
In the first argument of `optimize', namely `val'
In the expression: optimize val cont
```

where line 12:16-32 is `optimize val cont`.

Am I misunderstanding existential types in this case? Does the `forall v` in the declaration of `optimize` mean that `optimize` may expect from `a -> v` whatever `v` it wants? Or does it mean that `optimize` may expect nothing from `a -> v` except that `Ord v`?

What I want is that the `OptiF a v` is not fixed for any `v`, because I want to plug in some `a -> v` later on. The only constraint I'd like to impose is `Ord v`. Is it even possible to express something like that using existential types (or whatever)?

I managed to achieve that with an additional typeclass which provides an `optimize` function with a similar signature to `OptiF a v`, but that looks much uglier to me than using higher order functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is something that's easy to get wrong.

What you have in the signature of `optimize` is *not* an existential, but a universal.

...since existentials are somewhat outdated anyway, let's rewrite your data to GADT form, which makes the point clearer as the syntax is essentially the same as for polymorphic functions:

```
data Container a where
  (:/->) :: Ord v =>                       -- come on, you can't call this `Cons`!
     OptiF a v -> (a->Int) -> Container a
```

Observe that the `Ord` constraint (which implies that here's the `forall v...`) stands outside of the type-variable–parameterised function signature, i.e. *`v` is a parameter we can dictate from the outside when we want to construct a `Container` value*. In other words,

> For all `v` in `Ord` **there exists** the constructor `(:/->) :: OptiF a v -> (a->Int) -> Container a`

which is what gives rise to the name "existential type". Again, this is analog to an ordinary polymorphic function.

On the other hand, in the signature

```
optimize :: (forall v. (Ord v) => a -> v) -> Container a -> Int
```

you have a `forall` inside the signature term itself, which means that what concrete type `v` may take on will be determined by the *callee*, `optimize`, internally – all we have control over from the outside is that it be in `Ord`. Nothing "existential" about that, which is why this signature won't actually compile with `XExistentialQuantification` or `XGADTs` alone:

```
<interactive>:37:26:
    Illegal symbol '.' in type
    Perhaps you intended -XRankNTypes or similar flag
    to enable explicit-forall syntax: forall <tvs>. <type>
```

`val = (*3)` obviously doesn't fulfill `(forall v. (Ord v) => a -> v)`, it actually requires a `Num` instance which not all `Ord`s have. Indeed, `optimize` shouldn't need the rank2 type: it should work for any `Ord`-type `v` the caller might give to it.

```
optimize :: Ord v => (a -> v) -> Container a -> Int
```

in which case your implementation doesn't work anymore, though: since `(:/->)` is really an existential constructor, it needs to contain only *any* `OptiF` function, for *some* unknown type `v1`. So the caller of optimize has the freedom to choose the opti-function for any particular such type, and the function to be optimised for any possibly other fixed type – that can't work!

The solution that you want is this: *`Container` shouldn't be existential, either*! The opti-function should work for any type which is in `Ord`, not just for one particular type. Well, as a GADT this looks about the same as the universally-quantified signature you originally had for `optimize`:

```
data Container a where
  (:/->) :: (forall v. Ord v => OptiF a v) -> (a->Int) -> Container a
```

With that now, optimize works

```
optimize :: Ord v => (a -> v) -> Container a -> Int
optimize val (opti :/-> result) = result (opti val)
```

and can be used as you wanted

```
callOptimize :: Int
callOptimize = optimize val cont
   where val = (*3)
         opti val' = if val' 1 > val' 0 then 100 else -100
         cont = opti :/-> (*2)
```

Comment: You made my day and probably the next few ones :) What do you mean by 'existentials are outdated'? That they are subsumed by GADTs as said in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/GADT#Existential_types ? But I shouldn't replace ADTs by GADTs where not needed, right?

Comment: For simple constructors (but possibly many different ones) the old `data` syntax is arguably more readable, so: no, you shouldn't replace those with GADTs (there's nothing wrong with it, though!). For anything that involves type variables not mentioned in the data head, I would use GADT syntax.